# How to detect whether Java runtime is installed or not

Tags: c#, java, runtime

I program windows applications using Java and this builds a ".jar" file not an ".exe" file. When a client computer with no java runtime installed opens the ".jar" file, it runs as an archive with winrar. All I want to know is how to detect whether java runtime is installed or not on a computer using c# code in order to show a MessageBox telling user to install java runtime, or launches the ".jar" file using the java runtime if it's installed.

Comment: It only opens with WinRAR if they have WinRAR installed :).

Answer (score 11):

You can check the registry

```
RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine;
RegistryKey subKey = rk.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\JavaSoft\\Java Runtime Environment");

string currentVerion = subKey.GetValue("CurrentVersion").ToString();
```

Comment: You might want to open the registry using both `RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64)` and `RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32)` [for better detection](https://gist.github.com/sandrock/358bdd579b9decc64ca58c82e3ee23ef).

Answer (score 7):

Start 'java -version' in a childprocess. Check exitcode and returned output for versioninfo

```
    List<String> output = new List<string>();
    private bool checkIfJavaIsInstalled()
    {
        bool ok = false;

        Process process = new Process();
        try
        {
            process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c \"" + "java -version " +  "\"";

            process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((s, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Data != null)
                {
                    output.Add((string) e.Data);
                }
            });
            process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((s, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Data != null)
                {
                    output.Add((String) e.Data);
                }
            });

            process.Start();
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            process.BeginErrorReadLine();

            process.WaitForExit();

            ok = (process.ExitCode == 0);
        }
        catch
        {
        }

        return (ok);
    }
```

Comment: Java often installs itself without updating the system path.  Under those conditions, this method would not work.

Answer (score 5):

You could check in the registry. This will tell you if you have a JRE, and *which version*.

From [this document](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/version.html#jre-jdk):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\<version number>
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\<version number>
```

where the  includes the major, minor and the patch version numbers; e.g., 1.4.2_06

Comment: It should be noted that "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\<version number>" cannot be accessed programmatically using the RegistryKey C# functions.

Answer (score 1):

A small applet in a html page which cancels a redirect to a "Please install Java" page.

EDIT:  This is almost the only really bullet-proof way.  Any registry key containing JavaSoft is most likely only for the Sun JVM and not any other (like IBM or BEA).