# How to detect presence and location of JVM on Windows?

Tags: java, windows, jvm

I'm trying to detect if there is a JVM installed and where it is located so I can run `java.exe`.

All I've managed to find is `HKCU\Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\<ver>`. Is it safe to assume that it is installed in `%PROGRAMFILES%\Java\jre<ver>`?

I'm trying to do this in C#, but I assume the answer is pretty language agnostic, so any answer is appreciated.

**EDIT:** Ok silly me, I found [How to detect whether java runtime is installed or not on a computer using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855937/how-to-detect-whether-java-runtime-is-installed-or-not-on-a-computer-using-c) which pointed me at `HKLM\Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\CurrentVersion` which works with `HKLM\Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\<ver>\JavaHome`. I managed to find these instead underneath `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment`. Is there some way to detect which of these I should be checking without trying to sniff at the CPU type?

Comment: Does the registry entry contain all the versions of Java though? Because some applications have older versions of JRE bundled with them and may overwrite your previous registry entries, which is a real pain.

Comment: @biziclop It contains all the versions side by side with the CurrentVersion key described above pointing to the default JRE

Comment: That's nice to know, thank you. My remark still stands though, don't trust the current version blindly. :)

Comment: Don't trust this key either... Just investigated and my keys point to outdated client jvm.dll which has been removed instead of the newer server jvm.dll that is now used for client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to throw my hat in the ring with the code I've ended up using:

```
string javaDirectory = null;

// Native registry key - 32b on 32b or 64b on 64b
// Fall back on 32b Java on Win64 if available
RegistryKey javaKey =
    Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Javasoft\\Java Runtime Environment") ??
    Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Javasoft\\Java Runtime Environment");

if (javaKey != null)
{
    string javaVersion = javaKey.GetValue("CurrentVersion").ToString();
    try
    {
        javaDirectory = javaKey.OpenSubKey(javaVersion).GetValue("JavaHome").ToString();
    } catch(NullReferenceException)
    { /* Ignore null deref, means we can't get a directory */ }
}

if (javaDirectory == null)
{
    // deal with a lack of Java here.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A properly installed JVM on a windows system will (most likely..) respond to the command shell command:

```
java -version
```

This does not return the path, but try

```
java -verbose -version
```

(At least) one of the lines will contains the substring `rt.jar` and this line contains the path of the "active" java virtual machine.

Comment: Either that, or the registry entry for jars should be set. There's a WinAPI function to get file associations, but I forgot about it.

Comment: On my dev pc at least, this is not true. `java` isn't registered in `PATH`. In general, I think relying on `PATH` on Windows is a bad idea, simply because so many apps don't bother with it.

Comment: @Christian file associations aren't reliable either. Some archive managers overwrite the jar association.

Comment: @Matthew Scharley - I agree, but it's still a possible further check.

Comment: @Andreas that said, you are technically correct, and I've seen this repeated a lot on the internet when looking for an answer to this. But from personal experience, I've needed to tweak `PATH` for quite a few apps that were supposed to set it up properly.

Comment: @Matthew - A java installation on windows drops some `java.exe` into the windows (or ./system32) folder. I don't have a special entry on my `PATH` environment - but it works as described above.

Comment: @Andreas Now I'm curious. Do you have the JRE or the JDK? I have the Oracle JRE downloaded from http://java.com/ . It's entirely possible that we have two different JRE's and we are both correct.

Comment: @Matthew - java -version tells JRE 1.6.0_21, it has been installed through the standard oracle JDK (!) installer and I have no `PATH` entry pointing to the install directory. `javac` can't be resolved from the console, the `java` call executed `C:\WINDOWS\system32\java.exe`

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the JRE install a java.exe in c:\windows?

Comment: It didn't on my PC, not anywhere in PATH. (win7 64)

Comment: This just prompted me to do a search on my `C:\ `, found it in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`. Must be an analogous idea to `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node`. IMO, looks like MS seriously screwed up x86 compatibility...

Comment: @MatthewScharley Ah thankyou, lets see if I can finally get eclipse to run.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to get "*JAVA_HOME*" environment variable.

It's could be helpful.

**EDIT:**

Better idea look por "*CLASSPATH*" variable.

```
------- start --------
C:\Documents and Settings\david>set
ALLUSERSPROFILE=...
APPDATA=...
CLASSPATH=.;C:\Archivos de programa\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip
CommonProgramFiles=...
...
----- end ----
```

Comment: Also unfortunately not setup properly on my dev PC. Definitely worth a first shot attempt though. Can you include an example output for my benefit please?

Comment: I'm looking at the environment variables of a PC with newly installed Java JRE.

I have not found the varialbe "JAVA_HOME" (my mistake, sorry) but if a so-called "CLASSPATH" that can be helpful.