# how to check if user has java runtime environment installed

Tags: c#

i have built an application that needs to run with java runtime environment and want to work out how i can check if users machine has it installed is there a simple way to check for this so i could check on application startup if user has it installed conitnue with application if needed to install show message box or hyperlink to oracle download.

Thanks guys

Comment: this identical question is 13 years old, but it may still work [How to detect whether java runtime is installed or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855937/how-to-detect-whether-java-runtime-is-installed-or-not)

Comment: I tried to run that code results in null always so im not sure if its still working if its outdated?

Comment: do you have a JRE installed? Can you check the registry manually to be sure the entry is there?

Comment: Yeh i did mine is in the register for some reason it returns null even tho its in the register

Comment: going to need more info on the code then, because if there is a registry key then it should return a value and not `null`. Do you have a typo of some sort, or is the registry subtly different now than years ago?

Comment: Nah its not thats the weird  thing tomorrow ill post my code and a screenshot of my registry path